# Subversion client with multiple check-ins at once?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, workflow

I use and love Subversion and TortoiseSVN. However, there is one feature I sorely miss:

I work on a big project whose source files are on an external server. Each time I click "SVN Commit..." from Windows Explorer, TortoiseSVN will search the whole tree for changes, which takes a lot of time.
However, many of the changes I am about to comment and commit refer to one or two files only, which means that I have to repeat the "SVN Commit..." procedure up to a dozen times, every time with the full tree rebuild.

Is there a way in TortoiseSVN to create multiple commits (with different comments) without rebuilding the "Changes Made" list every time or, alternatively, does anybody know a tool that can?

Comment: Sounds like you're ready to switch to git ;-)

Comment: or not checkout the entire repository, or localize your commits to where you've worked.

Comment: @hacker and @elder_george: I appreciate both Git and Mercurial very much, but the issue here as @Avi says, is the fact that he's working on an external server. Git and Mercurial will also suffer from slowness in this scenario.

Comment: azkotoki, `git gui` would definitely make it easier with multiple scans. But then this is why we comment instead of answering.

Comment: hacker, your last comment is very useful and interesting (even I upvoted it). The first one smells to fanboy-talk and is misleading. It's a matter of information quality, regardless the answering facility you use.

Comment: azkotoki, the first one was a joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the TortoiseSVN menu of the working copy (right click on the working copy), pick "Check for modifications". This will give you a dialog that lists all your changes. (It won't refresh automatically, you'll have to do this manually.) In this dialog you can select the files you want to commit (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+left click) and (using right click) commit only those.

I always have one such dialog open while working on some working copy.

Comment: Pekka, also look at the "Move to changelist" item at the end of the right-click menu for files/folders in this dialog. I sometimes find changelist  helpful. (This is all local, so you can freely play around with this without having to fear to mess up something in the repo.)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like you shouldn't be working on files on an external server. TortoiseSVN works much better when the working copy is local. There are other ways of keeping it synchronized with an external server, if you need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.5, Subversion supports [changelists](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.5_releasenotes.html#changelists), which sounds as if it could help you. It lets you arrange your changes into named lists, and submit them all at once. TortoiseSVN [supports changelists](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/tsvn_1.5_releasenotes.html#changelist-support), too.

To be honest I'm not 100% sure if using changelists will help in your situation, but it might at least be worth a try. I'm thinking that the client-side arrangement of changes into known sets should cut down on the amount of searching that needs to be done.

Comment: I am going to go with sbi's answer but changelists look very interesting in the long run, as they seem to help with ongoing developments. Thanks for the tip!